# How to call named routes from blade which are declared in routes/api.php

Tags: laravel, api

Consider these line in routes/web.php

```
Route::group(['prefix'=> '/task','as'=>'task.'] , function ( ) {
    Route::get('/list',[TaskController::class,'index'])->name('list');
    Route::post('/create',[TaskController::class,'create'])->name('create');
    Route::post('/update/{task}',[TaskController::class,'update'])->name('update');
});
```

We can simply call this named routes from blade file this way

```
{{route('task.create')}}
```

But if these same lines are in **routes/api.php**

How can we call in blade file. I tried this way

```
{{route('api.task.create')}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these named routes are in api.php

```
Route::group(['prefix'=> '/task','as'=>'task.'] , function ( ) {
    Route::get('/list',[TaskController::class,'index'])->name('list');
    Route::post('/create',[TaskController::class,'create'])->name('create');
    Route::post('/update/{task}',[TaskController::class,'update'])->name('update');
});
```

We can call route in blade file using this

```
  {{route('task.create'}}
```

Comment: The routes in `api.php` are prefixed with `/api`, the routes in `web.php` are not. They are not interchangeable. If you want to call a named route, you give it a name.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the name as well  in the `routes\api.php` file

```
Route::group(['as'=>'api.'] , function ( ) {
    Route::group(['prefix'=> '/task','as'=>'task.'] , function ( ) {
        Route::post('/create',[TaskController::class,'create'])->name('create');
    });
});
```

so you can call it like this:

```
{{route('api.task.create')}}
```

you may check: `php artisan route:list` to see the name assigned to double check.

Comment: I don't want to use these routes in web.php , I want to use in routes/api.php. I need the solution for that

Comment: that is supposed to go in the api.php file

Comment: Yes I have placed this code in api.php but how can i call from blade file? using this kind of pattern {{route('api.task.create')}}

Comment: Run:  php artisan route:list and you will see all the routes that are created in your project, including the ones in the api.php file.  one of the columns shows you the "name" you should call from blade

Comment: Thanks a lot. got the solution. It will be the same what ever the route file is api.php / web.php